# transactional not working in spring data neo4j

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I am using *spring-data-neo4j* for my *neo4j* database in my application,i want to have *transactional APIs* in my service layer but it seems that *@transaction* is not working.

Service Layer:

```
    @Transactional('neo4jTransactionManager')
    def savePerson(){
        Person person=new Person()
        person.setName("prabh")
        person.setDistance(100)
        PersonRepository.save(person)
        int i=10/0;
    }
```

Configuration :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="neo4j"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService"
        class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data" />
    </bean>

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"
        base-package="neo4j" />

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="neo4j" />


    <bean id="neo4jTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <bean class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager">
                <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="userTransaction">
            <bean class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.UserTransactionImpl">
                <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="neo4jTransactionManager" />

</beans>
```

I am using rest server of *neo4j* database.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the documentation says, for remote access there is no transactionality due to Neo4j's REST API not exposing transactions over the wire in the past

In the next milestone (and the current 3.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) build a new remoting integration is used, which exposes transactions over the wire and is also much faster than the existing one.

Comment: Is there any timeline for next release and are you sure that we will get this support in next release.Also what is the difference b/w rest and embedded mode,which one is better in terms of production level usages considering scaling,performancece etc.